# Building an R package: Error "translate_lapack.hpp:1247: undefined reference to `ilaenv_'"

Tags: r, package, rcpp, devtools

When I run `devtools::document()` on my R package (which includes C++ code), I get multiple errors of the type

> C:/Users/Lennart/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/RcppArmadillo/include/armadillo_bits/translate_lapack.hpp:1247: undefined reference to `ilaenv_'

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an incomplete question---we have no code to go by, and have no idea how you set your package up.

Note that for `RcppArmadillo` you *must* use the snippets provided [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/tree/master/inst/skeleton) (and automatically included by `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()`) in order to get the correct files `src/Makevars` and `src/Makevars.win` which have

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS) 
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS) $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

which ensures working OpenMP (if R has it on the architecture) and working LAPACK / BLAS.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have all dependencies installed (LAPACK is an external library for linear algebra, perhaps you need to install some collection of development packages). It might also mean that you've got some dependency in a wrong (outdated? too new?) version.

What exact environment is this? What exact versions of the relevant packages?